# Why not to use fork/vfork from C# code?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

mono code contains phrases:

> "it bypasses essential shutdown code" "Use System.Diagnostics.Process
>   instead".

How the shutdown code can be bypassed if two processes (after fork) are completely identical.

My idea is to rewrite `Process` class, that is why I can't use it. And I want to rewrite it, because it doesn't create a new virtual terminal and a new session.

Which shutdown code was referenced in the message?

Comment: Mix usage of fork with high level lang and multi-thread program will cause lots of deadlock, fd leak problems. DO NOT DO THIS unless you are an expert !

Comment: Which shutdown code was referenced in the message?

Comment: it is too broad, search google for `fork multithreaded`, and there will be lots of infos

Comment: exec terminates all threads, that's what i found, so don't see a problem in my situation. I just asking what "essential shutdown code" is mentioned in the message in question

Comment: The garbage collection and classes termination for sure